# NPE in Spring Integration LoggingHandler

Tags: java, spring, nullpointerexception, spring-integration

I'm facing some weird NPE with no details thrown by `org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler`. The previous log entry is 2 minutes before which is also strange.

Does anyone have any idea what can be the reason behind it?

```
2017-07-25 18:33:38.561 DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'markEodPositionsAsProcessedChannel'
2017-07-25 18:35:36.985 ERROR o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
            at org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.processMessage(MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.java:96)
            at org.springframework.integration.handler.ServiceActivatingHandler.handleRequestMessage(ServiceActivatingHandler.java:89)
            at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:109)
            at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
            at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
            at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:148)
            at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.access$000(UnicastingDispatcher.java:53)
            at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher$3.run(UnicastingDispatcher.java:129)
            at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor$1.run(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:55)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you talk about looks like:

```
public T processMessage(Message<?> message) {
    try {
        return this.delegate.process(message);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        throw new MessageHandlingException(message, e);
    }
}
```

The clearly means that `delegate.process()` throws `NPE` somehow.

According to the StackTrace you have some Service Activator to call your POJO service method. And that looks like exactly your method already throws that `NPE`.

I also believe that there is something else in the StackTrace after `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException`.

You see that as an `ERROR` in your logs, because you have some polling flow starting from some source - Inbound Channel Adapter. And any exception thrown downstream are caught by the error handler in the Poller Ednpoint and sent to the `errorChannel` with the `LoggingHandler` as a default subscriber.

See [Reference Manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/configuration.html#namespace-errorhandler) for more info.